# Is this how I should handle passing data between view and modal segue view

Tags: ios, ios5, segue

Here's what I'm doing.  I have a table view controller with results on it.  When this view initially loads it also loads the search options.  This is essentially four arrays of data.  When this is loaded should I instantiate the search modal controller and pass it the arrays, or should I pass them each time I load the segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a segue to transition to your search modal controller, then your search controller will be instantiated by the segue.  You can pass whatever data is needed by your search controller in your implementation of the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Comment: So I should hold all the data in the main view, and just pass it when I segue?  That's the way I went with, I just wanted to make sure that was the best way.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best way.